# PHP 4 Default Function Parameter

Tags: php, function, arguments

can I use this syntax under PHP 4 (default function parameter) :

```
function myFunction($arg1 = 'defaultValue') {}
```

Thanks.

Comment: if it is a question, the answer is yes.

Comment: Actually, I would very much encourage use of default parameters in every function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. And it can be overwritten like this:

```
<?php
$var = 'one';
myFunction($var);

function myFunction($arg1 = 'defaultValue') {
echo $arg1;
}
?>
```

the output would be `one`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you definitely can do.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you simply try it? yes, you can.

Comment: I use php 5 on my dev machine but I want my code to be compatible with php 4 too...